# Nginx reverse proxy backend returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: nginx, fastapi, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have an application on a server, the frontend runs on port 5173 and the backend runs on port 8000.

When I send a request on the instance `curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000` I get data.

When I get into the browser(`http://instance-ip/`) the front end is getting called and it displays on my browser. When I try to call the backend from the frontend I get: `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/test net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

This is my Nginx config:

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name instance-ip;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5173;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
```

Im a beginner and I need some help. Thank you.

Comment: why are you calling `http://127.0.0.1:8000/...` instaed of `http://instance-ip/api/search/test` ?